# How to loop through all task folders in Outlook?

Tags: vba, outlook

This Outlook VBA code loops through all the folders and debugs their names.

I can get the default folder for tasks

```
Set ObjTaskFolder = ObjNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks)
```

I have two task folders and I need all the items (Tasks) within these folders.

I don't want to check all the folder items with `.class=oltask` so I am looking for a way to evaluate at folder level.

```vb
Set ObjNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")            
    
For f = 1 To ObjNS.Folders(1).Folders.Count
    Debug.Print ObjNS.Folders(1).Folders(f)
    If (ObjNS.Folders(1).Folders(f).Class = olTask) Then
        'Task folder
    End If
Next f
```

I am looking for a way to evaluate folders, for the task folder only and then loop through all the items in within?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the `MAPIFolder.DefaultItemType` property is `OlItemType.olTaskItem` (`=3`) or the `MAPIFolder.DefaultMessageClass` property is "`IPM.Task"`.